# RunProcess in WolframCloud

Tags: processlink

In Wolfram cloud `RunProcess@$SystemShell` returns the following error:

`RunProcess::pnfd: Program /bin/sh not found.  Check Environment["PATH"].`

but `Environment["PATH"]` gives

`/usr/local/Wolfram/WolframEngine/latest/Executables:/usr/local/Wolfram/WolframEngine/latest/SystemFiles/Graphics/Binaries/Linux-x86-64:/bin:/usr/bin`

and $SystemShell gives

`/bin/sh`

It is true that you cannot execute shell commands in the cloud, but that error seems to come from the package `ProcessLink.m` and it can be reproduced in CDFPlayer
why ProcessLink functions give that error? is there something that can be tweaked to make ProcessLink functions to work at least in CDFPlayer? 
Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I believe `RunProcess` is not available either in the cloud or the free CDF player, for security reasons.

Comment: I don't see any problem for it to work in the cloud, like Google Colab does for example.

Comment: In the WolframCloud, if you eval `ReadString@"!date"` it explicitly tells you that you cannot execute that command in sandbox mode; this looks like a security measure. On the other hand, in CDF, you can eval any `ReadString@"!command"` issues, but nothing like `RunProcess@"command"` cause it returns with that weird `::pnfd` `..not found`  error

Comment: If you use the Wolfram Enterprise Private Cloud, and switch off sandboxing in the configuration, you can run RunProcsss, ExternalEvaluate and more.

Comment: Thanks @RolfMertig , do you have a clue regaarding why `RunProcess` does not  work with the kernel installed by CDFPlayer? thanks

Comment: No, why don't you ask Wolfram support?